# Flutter Firebase StreamBuilder how to use only one specific document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My Code is working but there is a problem it runs 4 times I think problem is Document number. In Firebase Firestore I have 4 document but i need to use only one at a time. So How can i do this. I found some solutions but all of them old their code doesn't work ,  it seems to be changed. Here is the full code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('catanR').snapshots();
height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _usersStream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Something went wrong',
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Cairo', fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Material(
      child: ListView(
        children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          return Container( // THİS PART DOESN'T MATTER
```

**Actual Output is like this:**

[image]

**However, when I scroll because of the StreamBuilder and the document number, that number of screens appears. And as you guessed i just only need one without scrolling.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to tell what the issue is, from the screenshots. What exactly is not going as expected?

Comment: Problem is the first picture you see is our expected output. But because of a problem it is generating 4 page meaning 4 output. that is the problem I only need one output so one screen. As @Fakhri said problem is ListView it is working right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build it once, don't return a ListView and its children generated from the collection's docs, just return the container with the data[index]  you want to use.

Comment: It's duplicating the Container Widget which you are returning inside the listview builder. If you want to build it only once, you need to remove the ListView and put that Container as the Material widget's child and extract the data from your collection's docs just before the return statement.

Comment: okey understood. it works right know thanks